# Ext JS 4.2: Checkbox model selection issue

Tags: javascript, extjs

I recently switched to 4.2.1 from 4.1.3. I have a grid with check box model. When user select or deselect a record, app selects (or deselects) all relevant records based common record attribute value. This was working perfectly,but, after migration, stop works. When I looked at on FB, I can see two events fired (select and deselect)

```
var exSelectionModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
checkOnly: false,

viewConfig: {
    listeners: {
        beforecellmousedown: function(view, cell, cellIdx, record, row, rowIdx, eOpts){

        }
    }
},
listeners: {

    selectionchange: function(sm, selections) {

        console.log(selections);
    },


    select: function( sm, record, index, eOpts ){               

        var blockId = record.data.blockId;          

        var blockRecords = sm.getStore().queryBy(function(rec){
            return rec.data.blockId == blockId;


        var records = new Array();  
        Ext.each(blockRecords.items, function(bRec){                
            records.push(bRec);
        });

        sm.select(records,true,true);


    },
    deselect: function( sm, record, index, eOpts ){
        var blockId = record.data.blockId;


        var blockRecords = sm.getStore().queryBy(function(rec){
            return rec.data.blockId == blockId;
        });

        var records = new Array();  
        Ext.each(blockRecords.items, function(bRec){  
            records.push(bRec);
        });

        sm.deselect(records,true,true);
    }
}
```

});

Did anything change in Ext JS 4.2.1 from 4.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found an answer. I added following attributes

```
    checkOnly: true,
    allowDeselect: false,
    ignoreRightMouseSelection: true,
```

Something changed or is somewhere broken in 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

My problem with Checkbox selModel in ExtJS 4.2 is that I use grouping feature also and looks like they have a conflict